# How to close multiple selenium sessions by user`s wish?

Tags: python, selenium, multiprocessing

I launch multiple selenium sessions with multiprocessing and want to close them all or a few when user wants it

schema of my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def drop():
    ...
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.join(path, '\\chromedriver.exe'),chrome_options=options)
    ...

for i in range(10):
     s=Process(target = drop)
     s.start()
input('press enter to stop all sessions')
###close selenium driver event
```

Comment: Store the processes in a list and run `.terminate()` on all of them.

Comment: @KlausD. I edited the question, it was incorrect

Answer (score 0):

you can create an array `process_list = []` and append the 's' variable in the list for every iteration `process_list.append(s)` and then to stop all processes

```
for i in process_list:
  driver.close()
  i.terminate()
```

Comment: The problem is to get all the driver variables

Answer (score 0):

Adding each driver instance to a list when creating them and then iterating through them one by one to close them afterwards might be able to solve your issue.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

list_drivers = []

def drop():
    ...
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.join(path, '\\chromedriver.exe'),chrome_options=options)
    list_drivers.append(driver)
    ...

for i in range(10):
     s=Process(target = drop)
     s.start()

input('press enter to stop all sessions')

for driver in list_drivers:
  driver.quit()

###close selenium driver event
```